# For each 820 bytes save to new file

Tags: python, binary

I have a file ( size : 20 mb | binary file ) that needs to be parsed every 820 bytes and that very content of 820 saved into a new file with the name of the file being the string(ASCII) between the 2byte and the 16byte mark.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
    ^ THE FILENAME COMES FROM HERE    ^
```

Ok, now that the challenge is explained (I hope) what I do have for now is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("file", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read()
    if byte > 820:
        print "Reach the 1 record mark on the File you have defined "
```

But I can also see a possibility here:

```
for f.read(820) in file:
   a = f.read()
   b = open("Iam_from_2_to_16_byte_string", w)
   b.write(a)
   b.close
```

Well what I dont know is how to iterate for the first 820 bytes  and then the next 820 bytes and the next until the end of the file and ofc the hardest part that is grabbing every time I do that new file the 2 to 16 byte buffer and use it as a filename in every new file I have with the 820 bytes .

Answer (score 4):

The [`iter()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) can be passed a function and a sentinel, use that to read a file in 820 byte chunks:

```
for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(820), ''):
    # chunk is now 820 bytes long, until the last chunk which *could* be shorter.
```

Every iteration, the `lambda` function will be called, reading 820 bytes, until `f.read(820)` returns an empty string (signifying EOF).

The chunk is just a string, so you can use slicing to get your filename:

```
filename = chunk[2:16]
```

Used together:

```
with open("file", "rb") as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(820), ''):
        open(chunk[2:16], 'wb').write(chunk)
```

Comment: Very nice - that form of `iter` is often overlooked :) +1

Comment: hmmm i get a error Martijn do you know why ? 

drdos@poison:~/work$ python 1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 5, in <module>
    open(chunk[2:16], 'wb').write(chunk)
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '112011142635//'
drdos@poison:~/work$ 

the code i have is this : 

`code`
with open('/home/drdos/work/PTSIBS01.PDA', "rb") as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(820), ''):
        open(chunk[2:16], 'wb').write(chunk)
`code`

Comment: @PythonNewbie: What does `print chunk[2:16]` give you? Sounds like the chunk is smaller than 820 bytes.

Comment: the 2:16 is the filename i want for each file of 820 bytes

Comment: Yes, I understood that; I wanted to help you debug your problem, as the code appears to try and open a directory name instead. It looks as if the value of `chunk[2:16]` ends in two slashes, making it an invalid filename.

Comment: may have something to do with the file when i see the file i see the double slashes.. and other stuff that can confuse the filename

Comment: @PythonNewbie: You'll have to clean those filenames up using an extra function of sorts; perhaps replace slashes with underscores or similar. Note that that is a new issue, quite outside the scope of your original question. :-) Perhaps you can create a new question for that; list some examples of filenames you found and ask for advice on how to clean those up if you are having trouble with that part.

Comment: its a .pda file the first part of the file is just like this :

07112011142635//PT    1023700000-V—c™n´‚¨š ¾[Çz•…±´†dŒiñÎ¸Z×§Fj~?Æ[-&o†àdé“ÔÊŽrùÕ2ÿNXï”©®ãó,ÆsÉÄ_Ë=R58‡Új;£ô™c&e‚×ïrÉDœÃx¿>z¥™˜ïüV.¯Q¼²â<

Answer (score 0):

Python's `file` method `read()` has an option argument that sets the number of bytes to read. It also leaves the filepointer at the end of the bytes read, so that any next call will start after the last byte previously read:

```
n = 820
with open("file", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(n)
        if not data:
            break
        # do stuff with data.
        # for example, get a filename
        filename = str(data[2:16])
```

That iterates over the file contents in steps of 820, until it reaches EOF.

Comment: god damn it ! u are good u made a solution in less then minutes that was quick thanks :)

Comment: hi, i try to run it with my script but doesnt create the different files with the 820 bytes and fileaname i want the c0de i have now is :

n = 820
with open('/home/drdos/work/01.PDA', "rb") as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(n)
        if not data:
            break
        
        filename = str(data[2:16])
        x = open("file_#{filename}", 'wb').write(data)